# vb.net is it possible to extend a system class?

Tags: vb.net, class, extend

I want to add a function to System.IO.Path Class.

The Problem is Path is NotInheritable.

So doing that is impossible:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Path : Inherits System.IO.Path

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Extension Methods. Those seem to be the functions of the extended class, but there is no real connection between them. They do make programming a bit more convenient though.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx

**Update:** Let's see an example. Note that these are snippets from 3 files.

```
'Noninheritable baseclass
Public NotInheritable Class BaseClass
    Function f()
        Return 42
    End Function
End Class

'Extension
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Module ExtModule
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub Print(ByVal bc As BaseClass)
        Console.WriteLine(bc.f())
    End Sub
End Module

'Usage
Sub Main()
    Dim bc As BaseClass
    bc = New BaseClass()
    bc.Print() 'Calling the extension method
End Sub
```

And it says `42`.

Comment: You cannot extend NotInheritable classes, AFAIK

Comment: It works. The official guys don't mention such problem in [their blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/03/10/extension-methods-best-practices-extension-methods-part-6.aspx). There are some restrictions, but I found nothing complicated.

Comment: Try to extend `Path` and you'll see. The OP wants to extend `Path`, specifically. The problem is that extension methods operate on instances, and you cannot instantiate a `Path`.

Comment: Extending Path like I did isn't possible, but that was just a try of me to extend the methods of path. The answer of Imre Gábor helped me to solve the problem. But be aware Path doesn't have a constructor, so you can't call new on it, as shown in the example! Thx @all for help!

Comment: Be aware the Extension() attribute requires .Net 3.5 or above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in inheriting a "system" class, but a `NonInheritable` one, which are by design and as the name suggests, not inheritable.

Why would you want to inherit it anyway? You extend (inherit) a class in order to add behavior to its *instances*. In the case of Path there are no instances, Path is just a "container" to group similar methods that deal with filesystem path manipulation.

What you should do is to create a [Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aaxss7da.aspx) for your additional methods or a NotInheritable class of your own.

Comment: Inherting just was one way I tried to extend the System.IO.Path functionality. I want to add my function "bla()" to the Path class, because I don't want to have another class for that bla() function.

Comment: @MaBi Your question was `is it possible to extend a system class?`, I assumed that "extending" means "inheriting", "subclassing", as would most OOP programmers understand it. I've updated the answer based on your comment.